# Thread.sleep inside synchronized block causes the other Thread to wait when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I have this simple thread:

```
aQueueThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while(!Thread.interrupted())
                        {
                            QueueElementWrapper wrapper = aRequestsQueue.take();

                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            synchronized(aQueueLock)
                            {
//                              Thread.sleep(2000);
                                aMainExecutor.submit(wrapper.aCallable);

                                if(wrapper.aRequestType == EQueueElementType.RELOGIN)
                                    aQueueLock.wait();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    }
                }
            }, "DownloaderThread");
            aQueueThread.setDaemon(true);
            aQueueThread.start();
```

There is a LinkedBlockingDeque (that is the aRequestsQueue reference) in the run loop.

Now, I am running in MainThread another method which also is using the synchronized block based on the aQueueLock. When I use the Thread.sleep() method outside of the synchronized block all is well. The MainThread starts as soon as this method leaves it's synchronized blo However, if I move it 2 lines lower, so it will be inside sychronized block, for some reason, the MainThread is waiting until the aRequestsQueue has no more elements inside, until it's allowed to enter the other methods synchronized block.

Can anybody solve this mystery for me?

//Edit

Ok, to exclude the reason inside the complicated code of mine, I scribbled quickly a test code. Created an empty android project with single Activity. I added a white 200x200 view to the main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view" 
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And modified the MainActivity to change the visibility of this view, like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    Object lockObject = new Object();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
                    {
//                      Thread.sleep(2000);
                        synchronized(lockObject)
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        new CountDownTimer(4000, 4000)
        {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                synchronized(lockObject)
                {
                    findViewById(R.id.view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I don't think it can get simpler than this. If you leave the sleep() invokation inside synchronized block, the white square appears after 10 seconds. If you comment that one, and leave the one outside the synchronized block, you will see the white square after 4 seconds.

Comment: I do not believe that `Thread.sleep()` will cause execution to continue in another thread.  From the JavaDoc: "The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors."  I believe to do that you need to use `Object.wait()`.  This will cause the currently running thread to give up it's current monitors and allow other threads to execute.

Comment: You should not be sleeping inside of something that other threads could wait on, especially if one of those is the main ("UI") thread which fundamentally should not sleep *or wait* for any meaningful amount of time.

Comment: @CodeChimp, oh no no you missunderstood, or maybe I wasn't clear enough. Let me clarify: I am not expecting the other thread to go into it's own synchronized block when I do the sleeping. I'm expecting it to go into when the lock on this object is being released when the first thread leaves it's own synchronized block, which it does (this loop iterates around 4 times). However what happens is, that even though the first thread leaves the synchronized block repeatedly, the MainThread is still waiting on the synchronized(aQueueLock) line. While if I move Sleep otside of synchronized all is well.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, I never stated I intend to sleep in there. I'm doing some tests, needed to sleep there for a bit, and noticed this strange behaviour.

Comment: Based on the comments above, I'd say there's no way for us to know what's going on unless you show us the code that _all_ of the other threads are executing.  Putting the sleep() inside the synchronized block is causing at least one other thread to block, and that is changing the order in which things happen.  Unless you show us what those things are, there's not much help we can offer.

Comment: @Lucas - fundamentally, there's no guarantee that who gets a lock will be handled in a "fair" manner, so one thread that grabs it over and over can indeed starve out others for long periods of time.  Of course if you sleep when *not* holding it, there's a fair chance someone else will indeed get a chance to grab it.

Comment: @james large, I would have to show you most of the core of the project I'm working on, and since it's propriotary I cannot do that.  I was hoping maybe this "sleep() inside/outside synchrronized block" will ring any bells. Maybe I will try to do some testing with some basic 2 threaded abstract project, and test these things, maybe this will leade me to the cause.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, but it's not the case here of grabbing a lock over and over again. This thread (aQueueThread) is being created only once, and what is happening really inside a synchronized block, is passing a Callable to the ExecutorService, and then it's leaving the synchronized block which should release the lock, and hence the MainThread should be able to aquire it. The thing is, that if I sleep inside a synchronized block it doesn't aquire it, and when I sleep 2 lines higher, it does. It is quite a mystery, ain't it? :)

Comment: No, it's not the slightest bit a mystery.  **If you sleep while holding a lock**, nobody else can possibly acquire that lock until you wake up and release it.  Further, **if you do this in a loop** (as your code is), it is entirely possible that you will keep getting that lock and effectively exclude other threads from an opportunity to obtain it for substantial periods of time.

Comment: Chris, but the loop is OUTSIDE of synchronized block, not INSIDE it. So effectively what should happen is this loop content, getting lock and releasing it over and over again. The problem is, that the other thread (MainThread) is not aquiring the lock (with sleep() inside synchronized), when the first Thread leaves it's own synchronized block. On the other hand, if sleep() is outside all is as expected (MainThread aquires lock immidietly after the first Thread finishes one of it's loops).

Comment: @Chris, james large - I Edited my Topic to include a snippet of the simple test project I quickly scribbled, and the problem is also seend there, in exactly same manifestation.

Comment: As you have been told several times now, **a thread which repeatedly acquires a lock can end up persistently denying other threads an opportunity to acquire it**.  Your added example just demonstrates this again.  You need to stop expecting it to be fair.  Try putting a very short sleep outside the lock as well and you *may* see that gives the other thread a fighting chance, but your real problem is in your expectation.

Comment: @Chris, oh, my applogies, I missed that point. Alright, I can accept that, but that still doesn't answer the main question. The thread aquires the lock and releases it the same number of times, with sleep() invokation inside the synchronized area and outside. The sleep() invokation does not change how/if and how many times the Thread does aquire the lock. And yet, the behaviour is completely different depending on where the sleep method is inside that loop. You still failed to answer that. I do understand your point and I appologise for me missing it. It doesn't however explain the issue.

Comment: No, it does explain this issue.  Again, when you sleep inside the lock, no one else can acquire it, and if you try to acquire it again soon after you wake up and release it, there's a chance you'll get it again before anyone else does.  But when you sleep outside the lock, there's a high chance someone else will get to grab it while you are asleep.

Comment: @Chris, Awsome, that's it. Wish you would answer it like that earlier, since this is the answer which explain it in a straightforward way. Would you mind Chris posting this message as your answer, I will give you a check mark. I've searched the web a bit, and indeed it missed me, that from java 1.6 the order in which threads aquire a lock is not deterministic or synchronous, but it's a race "who gets it first". And even though in this situation, one thread is doing a bit of a work after it exits it's synchronous block, the time it takes it must be very minor, hence the reaquiring of a lock.

Comment: The definition of insanity is doing the same thing repeatedly and expecting a different result.  As others have said, there is no rule that says a lock will be fairly passed out to all threads.  There is no "round robin" scheme at play, or calculation to ensure each and every thread waiting on some lock has equal processor time.  You are acquiring a lock, then sleeping inside the block that has that lock.  While you are asleep, nothing else can acquire the lock.  Once you release the lock, you loop again and grab the lock.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, there is also a high probability that a different JVM, or even a different system with more CPUs or such, could potentially effect the outcome.  Threading is a tricky business, and one should really understand it fully before trying to implement some complex threading and synchronization scheme.  I speak from the experience of bashing my head against a wall on this in one of my own projects.